# Redirect all HTTP traffic?

Tags: router, http, redirection

From the router, is it possible to, for example, display a maintenance message whenever someone tries to connect to a website?
I can't find any way to do this from the web interface (I'm using a netgear router, but any answer is appreciated!)

Comment: At first glance the answer is no. You should be a little more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, your current network configuration, and exactly what model of router you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but its probably not trivial, and may well require different firmware, and a fair amount of skill.

I can think of multiple ways of achieving this - but I can't tell you the exact steps to take for each because it will be OS independent, and probably fairly involved.  Some possibilities include -

1. Create a stand-alone website on an IP with a "Maintenance page" that answers regardless of the specified domain or URL (this can be done a lot of ways, including Apache and redirect scripts), and then get your router to return your web servers IP address when someone goes to that URL.
2. Set up a transparent proxy which intercepts all HTTP requests and redirects them to your given site.  I know you can do this with some iptables magic and Squid, but I expect that a simpler proxy like privoxy will work as well.
3. Add the IP address of the website you wish to have a "maintenance page" for to your webserver, and modify the network so that requests to that IP address go to your maintenance site rather then correct site.  (I'd advise against this solution)

If you are wanting to do it for ALL websites you might be able to get catch  & release / portal software on the router which intercepts all websites with custom catch page - just change the contents of that page and prevent anyone from actually getting "released" on it.